# CodeIgniter - Form Validation targeted to the second database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation

I have 2 databases. I can query database A by following:

```
$this->db->query
```

and database B by following:

```
$this->db_B->query
```

I want the form_validation library to target its rules (like is_unqiue) to $this->db_B instead of $this-db. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Form_validation library @ /system/libraries.

Form_validation.php

```
public function is_unique($str, $field)
{
    list($table, $field)=explode('.', $field);
    $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));

    return $query->num_rows() === 0;
}
```

You could easily [extend](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) this class and overwrite the is_unique method to use your alternate database configuration set.
You may as well just change the database configurations so $this->db points to the right one instead. Depends on what you want to do in the future and if you are using form validation on the other db as well.